# Unable to install Force.com IDE due to Error reading signed content

Tags: force.com-ide

I'm getting trying to install the Force.com IDE (from the standard update site per instructions [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_install.htm)) in my Eclipse Neon (v4.6.3), but I get an "Error reading signed content". Full details:

```
An error occurred during the org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust phase.
session context was:(profile=_Developer_eclipse_java-neon_Eclipse.app_Contents_Eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.CheckTrust, operand=, action=).
Error reading signed content.
Exception in opening zip file: <home>/.p2/pool/plugins/com.salesforce.ide_38.0.0.201701101558.jar
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue was related to the fact that I had previously installed and uninstalled the Force.com IDE in my Eclipse instance, which had evidently left some traces.

The solution that worked for me (inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25094583/error-when-try-install-plugin) answer):

- Shut down Eclipse
- Edit the package.xml file (for me it was in `~/.p2/pool`) to remove all references to `com.salesforce.ide` artifacts (of which there were many...)
- Install the Force.com IDE again

After that the install went through.

Unfortunately I do not see the Force.com perspective :-( Still working through that, even after following the troubleshooting tips shown [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.eclipse.meta/eclipse/ide_install_troubleshooting.htm). But I believe that is a separate issue so I'll post this answer in case anyone else has the install issue. Will update later if I can get the Perspective to show